# Repeating application in the Droid menu

Tags: java, android, class, menu

Just wondering if anyone has seen this problem and knows what might be wrong. I've constructed something of a library it has on the main page where you select A, B, C ... etc. and then it opens a page with buttons for whichever your choice is. Now the problem is when I load my app onto my phone it has one app button for the whole app and then it has one button for each A, B, C... etc .classes as in i can click on any of those and it opens directly from the phones menu. Its like the menu has been spammed and i don't think people would appreciate that. Anyone have any idea what it might be. Ive made an application that has a library type thing in it before and this problem never occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the MAIN and LAUNCHER intents from those other activities.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

> Activities that can initiate
>   applications have filters with
>   "android.intent.action.MAIN" specified
>   as the action. If they are to be
>   represented in the application
>   launcher, they also specify the
>   "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
>   category:

```
 <intent-filter . . . >
     <action android:name="code android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="code android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Also, work on your accept rate.